# How to get information about compile error in Oracle/TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm using TOAD to develop a stored function in an Oracle database. When I click the "run as script" button in TOAD, it tells me that the script was executed with 0 errors and 1 compile errors. Where do I see the specific compile error(s). I'm fairly new to TOAD so I might be missing something obvious about the interface like a tab/window to see such error messages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either add `SHOW ERRORS` to the end of the script, which will print the error message(s) to the "script output" tab, or compile the function using the "Execute Statement" command in Toad, which will cause the errors to be displayed in a box at the bottom of the editor.

Answer (score 12):

Or you can look in USER_ERRORS table afterwards

Answer (score 1):

2 things you can do

1. goto Toad, schema browser, select Invalid Objects will tell you where to look.
2. then load the package into the editor and select the function, right click, compile, wioll show you the errors

Answer (score 1):

Click on Database -> Procedure Editor in top tool bar.

Paste your code in this new editor window and execute by clicking green play button on top.

All the errors will be displayed in a new window at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me was to open my script in the procedure editor and compile it there.