# In TOAD, how to debug this error message (compiled but with compilation errors)?

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm running oracle SQL in TOAD,  and after fixing a number of syntax bugs, I'm left with this:;

```
[Error] Compilation (1: 1): Compiled with errors
```

How do I go about resolving this?
thanks!

[image]

Comment: This response should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7014172/1295942